# How to I select a Range based on active row in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set the cell colors of a range of cells based on the data that's been inputted.
The row will change based on what row is currently active, but the columns will remain the same.
I want to change the cell color to black if the active cell is "N/A". I keep getting Run-Time Error 13: Type Mismatch. I'm trying to color columns D:F in whichever row is currently selected. My snip of code is below.

```
Sub black_out_range()
Dim wsC As Worksheet
Dim jobRange As Range
Dim jobRange As Range

Set wsC = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set jobRange = Range("B10", Range("B10").End(xlDown))

jobRange.Select

If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
    For Each i In jobRange
    i.Activate
    
    If ActiveCell = "N/A" Then
        With wsC
            .Range(.Cells(4, i), .Cells(6, i)).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want talking about the #N/A error (when Vlookup does not find a match, for example), or a string "N/A" put there on a different way?

Comment: @frekles9287 It would be good to do some editing in the explanation of the problem. It is very hard to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually best to try to avoid using select and activate in VBA, especially when you are trying to loop through a range

This code will look at the values in column b starting at row 10 (to the last row of data) and then color d-f black is the value in B is "N/A".

```
Sub black_out_range()
Dim last_row As Long


last_row = Range("B10").End(xlDown).Row()

For i = 10 To last_row
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = "N/A" Then   'asumes you want to start looking at cell b10
        Range("D" & i & ":F" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not answer my clarification question, so I will try assuming that you try dealing with the real error `#N/A`. If so, please try the next code. It also avoids selecting, which does not bring any benefit, only consumes Excel resources decreasing the code speed:

```
Sub black_out_range()
 Dim wsC As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long

 Set wsC = Worksheets("Sheet1")
 lastR = wsC.Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row() 'it returns the last cell even with gaps in the range

 For i = 10 To lastR
    If IsError(wsC.Range("B" & i).Value) Then
        If wsC.Range("B" & i).Value = CVErr(2042) Then   'the error for '#N/A' type
            wsC.Range("D" & i & ":F" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End If
    End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

But, if you really have a "N/A" in those cells, please use the next version:

```
Sub black_out_range_bis()
 Dim wsC As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long

 Set wsC = Worksheets("Sheet1")
 lastR = wsC.Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row()

 For i = 10 To lastR
    If wsC.Range("B" & i).Value = "N/A" Then
        wsC.Range("D" & i & ":F" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @freckles9287: So, should I understand that you really should process a "N/A" string?